# How to clear ARP Table through code?

Tags: android, linux, android-wifi

I have an android tab with hotspot turned on. When other wifi enabled devices get connected to my android device , their IP Address and other details get stored in the ARP table and I can access those details by reading from "/proc/net/arp" and I am showing them in a list. But when one device gets disconneted from my hotspot enabled android tab then the corresponding details related to that device are not getting cleared from the ARP table(When I read "/proc/net/arp" , the ARP table still holds the details of disconnected device). I want to Clear the details of the device which is disconnected.

Here is the code (accessing ARP table)

```
public ArrayList<ClientScanResultSO> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables,
    int reachableTimeout) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResultSO> result = null;

    try {
        result = new ArrayList<ClientScanResultSO>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

            if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];

                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    boolean isReachable = InetAddress
                            .getByName(splitted[0]).isReachable(
                                    reachableTimeout);
                    String name = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).getHostName();
                    if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                        result.add(new ClientScanResultSO(splitted[0],
                                splitted[3], splitted[5], isReachable,name));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: you need to be root, arp command line util in net-tools uses ioctl() so I think you need a jni. What about busybox arp -d ?

Comment: sorry ioctl() won't work, you cannot run dalvik processes as root

Comment: so what to do to have only connected clients using static and dhcp ?

Comment: Hey if you get the answer can you share it?@user935143?